# Vimscript all matches

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm new to Vimscript but I am trying to find all the lines which contain @property.

What I am trying is:

```
norm! gg
wh search( "@property", "cW" ) != 0
    echo getline( "." )
endw
```

But this code has a deadlock. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t pass the `c` flag, or at least not every time. `c` specifies that a match at the cursor should be accepted – but `search()` always moves the cursor to a match!

For example,

```
let flags = "cW"

while search("@property", flags) != 0
    echo getline(".")
    let flags = "W"
endwhile
```